# gvim command-line mode :!start [windows command] returns Command not found error message

Tags: windows, vim, cmd

I'm trying to run a vimscript (that's in my vimrc) that copies certain files over to a new directory, were I could then compile my tex file and return a pdf. My code works, except it always pops up command-prompts on every command. I'm using a lot of bash commands to do this (not too proficient in vimscript yet).

To try to avoid the pop-ups, I found that if you're in a command prompt, typing

```
start /MIN copy foo.tex bar.tex
```

runs a command prompt in "minimized mode", i.e. no pop up. However, when in vim, typing in command-line mode:

```
!start /MIN copy foo.tex bar.tex
```

returns a "Command not found" error message. In fact, any command I put after !start doesn't work

```
!start echo hi -> Command not found
```

However, it works perfectly well if I type it in a command prompt.

I looked into :help command-line, but couldn't find anything. Also, I tried:

```
exe 'sav! bar.tex
```

but that moves the current file and the vim buffer. I tried :copy and :move, but they only manipulate text in the buffer.

I'm running GUI vim 8.0 on Windows 10. the code I ran is(not whole program):

```
     " move appropriate files
     silent! exe '!start /MIN copy  ' fnameescape(fileName) . ' ' .  fnameescape(compileDir) . '\cur' . fnameescape(fileName)
     silent! exe '!start /MIN echo ' . curDir . ' >'. compileDir .'\curDir.txt'
     silent! exe '!start /MIN echo ' . fileName . ' >' . compileDir.'\fileName.txt'
     silent! exe 'cd' fnameescape(compileDir)

     "compile and move the pdf
     silent! exe '!compile.bat'
     silent! exe '!mv ' . l:Name . '.pdf ' . l:curDir
```

Which I know if inefficient, but I just needed something quick to work. I tried using vim built-in functions when I find them. Note that this code works fine without "start /MIN"

Comment: Have a look at the "Vim Tips Wiki": [Execute external programs asynchronously under Windows](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Execute_external_programs_asynchronously_under_Windows). BTW: Why is the question tagged with "bash"? You are obviously using cmd.exe stuff.

Comment: Thanks! I'm sort of new to this all. I've fixed it. 
Also, your solution  _almost_ worked. The command prompt pop up and go much faster, but they still pop up, and it only works with small tex files. Sometimes, files don't get copied on time, so when I run the compiling program, it gives an error . However, it does work if I don't make the compiler asynchronous.

Comment: This sounds as if you should use a make and a Makefile to control your tex build. Or maybe craft all this into a batch file and just start the batch file from Vim. You might also want to read `:help tex` and `:help compiler-tex`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This improves my setup, but I can't seem to get the windows stop popping up